# Scaling nodejs app with pm2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pm2

I have an app that receives data from several sources in realtime using logins and passwords. After data is recieved it's stored in memory store and replaced after new data is available. Also I use sessions with mongo-db to auth user requests. Problem is I can't scale this app using pm2, since I can use only one connection to my datasource for one login/password pair.

Is there a way to use different login/password for each cluster or get cluster ID inside app?

Are memory values/sessions shared between clusters or is it separated? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by, 'only one connection for login/password pair'? What connection?

Comment: Sorry for that. Connection to sources I use to get realtime data.

Comment: I met the exact same problem. For "MongoDB doesn't allow multiple connections with the same login/password pair", can you find any document? I searched in mongodb.com but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood this question, you have a node.js app, that connects to a 3rd party using HTTP or another protocol, and since you only have a single credential, you cannot connect to said 3rd party using more than one instance. To answer your question, yes it is possibly to set up your clusters to use a unique use/pw combination, the tricky part would be how to assign these credentials to each cluster (assuming you don't want to hard code it). You'd have to do this assignment when the servers start up, and perhaps use a a data store to hold these credentials and introduce some sort of locking mechanism for each credential (so that each credential is unique to a particular instance).

If I was in your shoes, however, what I would do is create a new server, whose sole job would be to get this "realtime data", and store it somewhere available to the cluster, such as redis or some persistent store. The server would then be a standalone server, just getting this data. You can also attach a RESTful API to it, so that if your other servers need to communicate with it, they can do so via HTTP, or a message queue (again, Redis would work fine  there as well.

Comment: I'm afraid pushing to DB and polling from it will take a lot of time. We need to count every ms. But thanks for advice. I think I will use usual clusters after all, not PM2. Main thread will serve requests and workers will get data and give it to master. And I can easily get credentials from configs for each worker using ID as index of array.

Comment: I never said polling from DB, I only referenced the DB when I mentioned the part about re-distributing credentials across clusters. This part would only be done when servers start up, essentially you just need to somehow distribute a pool of credentials, where each server should have a unique credential. As far as the dedicated server is concerned, again, it doesn't have to be a persistent database, can just be an in-memory redis instance that publishes the data to clusters via pub/sub. A single redis 'emit' event is really fast, I really doubt it would lead to performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

'Realtime' is vague; are you using WebSockets?  If HTTP requests are being made often enough, also could be considered 'realtime'.

Possibly your problem is like something we encountered scaling SocketStream (websockets) apps, where the persistent connection requires same requests routed to the same process.  (there are other network topologies / architectures which don't require this but that's another topic)

You'll need to use fork mode 1 process only and a solution to make sessions sticky e.g.:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sticky-session

I have some example code but need to find it (over a year since deployed it)

Basically you wind up just using pm2 for 'always-on' feature; sticky-session module handles the node clusterisation stuff.
I may post example later.

Comment: I wish I could use WS, but I'm limited by using poll and streams. Streams are not so bad after all :)

Comment: sticky-sessions in general and that module in particular may still be issue/of-use; if sessions are maintained per process/core.